# 'First' one is just sightseeing

Tags: riddle, mathematics, cipher

> irpasoapcopais5 T°,ř1q 850712ab996afedfbb7eb36bc3511dbc  →179.64691259
>
> fstrtnmsendrtmd 6°B'Q".4 aff8aa93caedee91d0113e01f200b84c↑16.88455024

name the sleeping giant,

find his home,

in "pain".

Hint 1:

> T°,ř1q decimal degrees, 6°B'Q".4 deg/min/sec This I think is too hard, I meant **character map** needs to be used for this section.

Hint 2:

> Sleeping giant is a mountain, Sleafar's 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> parts are correct. You guys can move on from that point.

Comment: Fun fact: 16° 88' 45.5024" N 179° 64' 69.1259" E is in Warendorf, Germany.

Comment: Hm, I took the → to imply east, which put me right in the middle of the Pacific! :-)

Comment: I checked on another site and it seems like google tricked me :(

Comment: @Tweakimp It's B64 (a regional road) which is shown in Warendorf, not `16° 88' 45.5024" N 179° 64' 69.1259`. And, btw N179° is not possible at all.

Comment: With Hint1, and using a character map the values for the coordinates become T°,ř1q = 54.34549113º (in decimal degrees) and 6°B'Q" = 54º66'81" (in degrees/minutes/seconds)

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken apparently you have found the way to decipher it but results are not quite correct.

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken you used 'T'=0x54 as if it's decimal, should be 84

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

### Part 1

> `irpasoapcopais5`
>  `fstrtnmsendrtmd`
>
>  Start reading at the letter bottom left, then go up, right, down, right and repeat. Then you get the following hint (which was obvious anyway):
>
>  **first parts on map second part is md5**

## Part 2

> `T°,ř1q`
>  `6°B'Q".4`
>
>  Nothing I tried with this delivered something meaningful. Because of the **°**, **'** and **"** they appear to be coordinates.

### Part 3

> `850712ab996afedfbb7eb36bc3511dbc`
>  `aff8aa93caedee91d0113e01f200b84c`
>
>  These are obviously MD5 hashes. It is not possible to reverse the algorithm to find out what was hashed here, however we can find matching hashes for 2 words using Google:
>
>  **octans**  (not sure what is meant here, it could mean to convert data in part 2 to octal notation, but as stated there I didn't get anything meaningful)
>  **occasus** (Latin for [west](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/occasus))

### Part 4

> `→179.64691259`
>  `↑16.88455024`
>
>  These could be coordinates as well, or maybe a point relative to that in part 2.

### Part 5

> No idea if this is anywhere close, but there is a [Sleeping giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%C3%B1a_de_los_Enamorados) in S**pain**.

Comment: In Part 3 (SPOILER ahead): the word octans may be the latin name for [octant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(instrument))